# LYAH - Understanding comment about "tell" when chaining Writer monads

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation, rewriting, writer-monad

Question is in bold at the bottom.

LYAH gives this example of using the `do` notation with the `Writer` monad

```hs
import Control.Monad.Writer

logNumber :: Int -> Writer [String] Int
logNumber x = writer (x, ["number " ++ show x])

multWithLog :: Writer [String] Int
multWithLog = do
              a <- logNumber 3
              b <- logNumber 5
              return (x*y)
```

where the definition can be re-written without the `do` notation:

```hs
multWithLog = logNumber 3 >>= (\x ->
              logNumber 5 >>= (\y ->
              return (x*y)))
```

So far so good.

After that, the book introduces `tell`, and edits the definition of `multWithLog` like this:

```hs
multWithLog = do
              a <- logNumber 3
              b <- logNumber 5
              tell ["something"]
              return (x*y)
```

which again can be rewritten as:

```hs
multWithLog = logNumber 3 >>= (\x ->
              logNumber 5 >>= (\y ->
              tell ["something"] >>
              return (x*y)))
```

Then the book makes the a point which appears unclear to me, if not inaccurate:

> It's important that **`return (a*b)`** is the last line, because the result of the last line in a **`do`** expression is the result of the whole do expression. Had we put **`tell`** as the last line, **`()`** would have been the result of this **`do`** expression. We'd lose the result of the multiplication. However, the log would be the same.

Therefore, here my first doubt comes: if `tell` results in `()`, then the code should not and does not even compile, as the `()` cannot match the expected type `Int`, nor any other type other than `()` itself; so what is the author trying to tell us? To make this non-opinion-based, **has something changed in Haskell, since the book was written, that made the above quoted statement unclear/inaccurate?**

Comment: If you remove the `return (x*y)` line, then this will indeed not compile, since then `()` would be the result. I do not really see what problem you face with the quoted paragraph?

Comment: For one thing it ends with _the log would be the same_. Which log, if the code does not even compile?

Comment: well the author probably assumes that you change the signature to `Writer [String] ()` :). In that case the result will be `()` but it will still write `["something"]` to the log.

Comment: That edge case is the only one that allows the code to compile. But if that is the signature, then the example totally loses its meaning...

Comment: well that is exactly the point of the author. That the last line is important, since otherwise the return value (and here type as well) is different.

Comment: If anyone reading this wants to play with this LYAH example and see if it still compiles, try the Jupyter adaptation of LYAH (chapter 13) https://github.com/jamesdbrock/learn-you-a-haskell-notebook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent re-write is further

```
multWithLog = logNumber 3        >>= (\ x ->
              logNumber 5        >>= (\ y ->
              tell ["something"] >>= (\ () ->     -- () NB
              return (x*y)       >>= (\ result ->
              return result ))))
```

and *that* is the `()` that `tell ["something"]` "returns". Obviously, the shuffled

```
multWithLog2 = logNumber 3        >>= (\ x ->
               logNumber 5        >>= (\ y ->
               return (x*y)       >>= (\ result ->
               tell ["something"] >>= (\ () ->
               return () ))))
```

would indeed have the type `Writer [String] ()`, so if the signature were to specify `Writer [String] Int`, it would indeed not compile.

Sans the type signature issues, the "log" i.e. the gathered `[String]` list would be the same with both variants, as `return` does not alter the collected output "log".